# Openfiledialog Multiselect

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am using a multiselect file dialog to browse multiple pictures and add them to a datagridview then from there store them in the database.

Something was wrong in term of that I only managed to store the first selected picture (No syntax or runtime errors at all).

Upon inspection I've realized that the file dialog gets the full path of the first image only and uses it for the rest of images.

Sample code:

```
if (ofd_pic.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   foreach (String file in ofd_pic.FileNames)
   {
    MessageBox.Show(ofd_pic.FileName);
   }
}
```

That messagebox will always show the path of the first image only and I wasn't able to get the path of every single selected image.

The properties of the file dialog are:

> 1.Modifiers: Private.
>   2. MultiSelect: True. 3. RestoreDirectory: True.

Any help?

Comment: How you say that it display only one path ? What happen when you select two file then it display filename with messagebox. What happen when you close that message box. Does other messagebox get popup?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're actually looping through all the files, but you never use it. You need to use the loop variable `file`

```
foreach (String file in ofd_pic.FileNames)
{
    MessageBox.Show(file);
}
```

`ofd_pic.FileName` property should be used only when you set `MultiSelect` to `false`, then only it makes sense. I guess `FileName` returns the first file when you have enabled `MultiSelect`.

Answer (score 1):

You have used wrong parameter.

```
if (ofd_pic.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
foreach (String file in ofd_pic.FileNames)
 {
 MessageBox.Show(file);
 }
}
```