# C# saving mulitple filenames from OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have a form with an add button.  When clicked, a user selects a file or files from the dialog.

**My Goal:**

Retrieve the names of all the files that a user selects (from whichever directory their file(s) are in) , copy those files in a specified folder that the user doesn't choose using File.Copy (I hard-code a filepath and filename).

**My Issue:**

If the user only selects one, this works fine.  For example:

`string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sfd.FileName)`;

This grabs the file.  Then:

```
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Is this published?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\NewTest\\" + txtAcronym.Text + "\\" + txtMajor.Text + "." + txtMinor.Text + "\\Published");
                File.Copy(sfd.FileName, "c:\\NewTest\\" + txtAcronym.Text + "\\" + txtMajor.Text + "." + txtMinor.Text + "\\Published\\" + name);
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\NewTest\\" + txtAcronym.Text + "\\" + txtMajor.Text + "." + txtMinor.Text + "\\NonPublished");
                File.Copy(sfd.FileName, "c:\\NewTest\\" + txtAcronym.Text + "\\" + txtMajor.Text + "." + txtMinor.Text + "\\NonPublished\\" + name);
            }
```

I ask the user if the document is published.  Based on the answer, it will create a directory and put the file in that directory.

Is it possible to loop through multiple filenames in the openFileDialog and put them all in a folder , rather than just one?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842396/openfiledialog-multiselect

Answer (score 3):

Set the Multiselect to true.

```
myFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
```

When the user accepts the selection, you can get them with `FileNames` property. It returns a **string[]**. Note the difference with `FileName` which returns **string**. You can use a for or foreach to get all the results.

```
foreach (string file in myFileDialog.FileNames)
{
    //do work
}
```